# Reloading JS scripts on page (transition) change when using Barba JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, barbajs

I'm trying to implement [barba.js](https://barba.js.org/) on a `HubSpot` site.

Consider the following two pages:

1. Resources
2. Customers

With my current `barba.js` implementation, this is the current flow I'm experiencing:

1. I access the `resources` page (not by transitioning to it, by directly accessing it via `/resources`).
2. At this point, all my `js` is working (`slick-sliders`, scroll functions etc)
3. I then use the navigation to access the `customers` page. The page loads, but all of the `js` specific to modules and forms for that page are not working.

In short, `js` for pages that I `transition` to do not work.

To resolve this, what I'm trying to do is to reload all `scripts` within the `container` `beforeEnter()`.

See below:

```js
$(function() {

  function delay(n){
    n = n || 2000;
    return new Promise((done) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        done();
      }, n);
    });
  }

  barba.init({
    sync: true,
    prefetchIgnore: true,
    debug: true,
    transitions: [{

      async leave(data){
        const done = this.async();
        await delay(200);
        done();
      },

      async beforeEnter({ next, container }) {

        $(container).find('script').each(function (i, script) {
          var $script = $(script);
          $.ajax({
            url: $script.attr('src'),
            cache: true,
            dataType: 'script',
            success: function () {
              $script.trigger('load');
            }
          });
        });
      },

      async enter(data){
        let scrollX = 0
        let scrollY = 0

        barba.hooks.leave(() => {
          scrollX = barba.history.current.scroll.x;
          scrollY = barba.history.current.scroll.y;
        });

        window.scrollTo(scrollX, scrollY);
      },

      async once(data){
        console.log("done");
      },

    }]
  });

});
```

However, my current `beforeEnter()` still yields the same results. Any way around this?

**Edit**

To provide more details, this `barba.js` implementation is for a `HubSpot` site. When you create `custom modules` in `HubSpot` it spits out the JS for that module on the page (in `script` tags). For example, here is how JS is rendered on the page:

```js
<script>
    // js from custom module is here
</script>

<script src=".../scripts-min.min.js"></script>
```

As such, when a `barba` transition is executed, I need all JS that have `src` and those that are rendered inline (like custom modules) to reload.

Latest approach based on [User863](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8053274/user863)'s feedback

```js
$(function() {

  function delay(n){
    n = n || 2000;
    return new Promise((done) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        done();
      }, n);
    });
  }

  function reload_scripts(param){
    $(param).find('script').each(function (i, script) {
      var $script = $(script);
      $.ajax({
        url: $script.attr('src'),
        cache: true,
        dataType: 'script',
        success: function () {
          $script.trigger('load');
          console.log("scripts loaded");
        }
      });
    });
  }


  barba.init({
    sync: true,
    prefetchIgnore: true,
    debug: true,
    transitions: [{

      async leave(data){
        const done = this.async();
        await delay(200);
        done();
      },

      async beforeEnter(data) {
        reload_scripts(data.next.container);
      },

      async beforeEnter({ next }) {
        reload_scripts(next.container);
      },

      async enter(data){
        // scroll to top of page when transitioning
        let scrollX = 0
        let scrollY = 0

        barba.hooks.leave(() => {
          scrollX = barba.history.current.scroll.x;
          scrollY = barba.history.current.scroll.y;
        });

        window.scrollTo(scrollX, scrollY);
      },

      async once(data){
        console.log("transition complete");
      },

    }]
  });

});
```

Current behaviour: Same as before (scripts for modules are broken when page changes). Modules with `slick slider`'s for example, do not work (`slick` isn't initiated).

Comment: Is the script with `src` are working?

Comment: @User863 - Yes, seems so. I have `js` that makes the `header` on scroll `fixed` and this `js` is executing when transitioning to another page. Just need a way to execute `js` on the page that has no `src`

Answer (score 0):

Might be solved by using `eval` as mentioned here: https://github.com/barbajs/barba/issues/32

Mentioned in the comments on the issue:

```
barba.hooks.after((data) => {
    let js = data.next.container.querySelectorAll('main script');
    if(js != null){
            js.forEach((item) => {
                console.log(js)
                eval(item.innerHTML);
            });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**According to docs**

The arguments of `beforeEnter` transition will be object of

| Property | Description |
| --- | --- |
| data.current | Current page related |
| data.next | Next page related |
| data.trigger | Link that triggered the transition |

https://barba.js.org/docs/advanced/hooks/#data-properties

Therefore the `container` property available inside both `data.current` and `data.next` properties. In this case, we have to use script from `data.next` which related to a new page.

**Fixed code #1**

```
async beforeEnter(data) {

    $(data.next.container).find('script').each(function (i, script) {
        // ...
    })
}
```

**Fixed code #2**

```
async beforeEnter({ next }) {

    $(next.container).find('script').each(function (i, script) {
        // ...
    })
}
```

Comment: Hi @User863 - slightly confused on the two "fixed code" approaches defined above, are you saying the the `AJAX` calls need to exist in both approaches? I've updated my question to showcase my current approach based on what I've interpreted from the above

Comment: @Freddy Ofcourse `AJAX` calls are needed in both approaches. Also, any one approach is enough.